# C struct initialization with C99 - Is mixing named and unnamed members valid?

Tags: c, c99, designated-initializer

Given the following:

```
struct example_struct
{
  char c;
  int i;
};
```

Is any the following initializer syntax valid in C99?

Syntax example #1

```
struct example_struct example = { 'a', .i = 1};
```

Syntax example #2

```
struct example_struct example = { .c = 'a', 1};
```

I am writing a simple struct parser and in my testing, this does not cause a compiler error using XCode 4.2.  I would like my parser to be C99 compliant.  My understanding (without a standard reference) is that a struct initializer should either have all unnamed or named (i.e. designated) members.

Should syntax example #1 and #2 be compiler errors?

If the examples are valid, what are the rules for the initialization syntax?

UPDATED QUESTION EXAMPLES

```
struct example_struct_3
{
  char c;
  int i;
  float f;
};

struct example_struct_3 example = { .i = 1, 1.0};
```

In the same main question, how would example three work?  I'm mainly confused about the arbitrary ordering of designated initializers with standard initializers.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to refer to the standard?

Comment: @CarlNorum, no I'd like to refer to the standard, I am just ignorant on where exactly to look.  Any info would be welcome.

Comment: is the question about mixing named and unnamed or about ordering when they are mixed?

Comment: Check out **6.7.8 Initialization**.  Particularly paragraph 17 may be of use to you.

Comment: @danh, both: I didn't know if it was valid, and if it is, what are the rules on ordering.

Comment: @CarlNorum, thank you I will review these rules.

Comment: Getting hold of C99 will be difficult now as it is superseded by C11.  However, you can get hold of C11 from [ANSI Webstore](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2fISO%2fIEC+9899-2012) for USD 30.  If you're doing anything significant, you need a copy.  You can poke around on [ISO JTC1/SC22/WG14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/) web site for drafts of the C standard, etc (and it is likely that a draft of C99 is the nearest you can get to C99 now).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both your initializations example 1 and 2 are valid C99/C11 initializations. You can mix designation initializers and non-designation initializers in an initializer list.

**EDIT:** regarding your new example 3, the initialization is also valid. After initialization, `example.c` has value `0`, `example.i` has value `1` and `example.f` has value `(float) 1.0`.

Comment: thank you for the info.  Is my example 3 valid?  Are mixed initializers valid as long as they are in order of the struct declaration?

Comment: @Josh yes: "a designation causes the following initializer to begin initialization of the subobject described by the designator. Initialization then continues forward in order, beginning with the next subobject after that described by the designator."

Comment: @ouah and Carl, thank you it is clearer now.  I will accept this answer when I am able (2 mins)